# Can there be mods for Xbox 360 Minecraft?

Tags: xbox-360, mods, minecraft-legacy-console

My brother has an Xbox 360 and Xbox Live/Gold.
We've done lots of research but can't find any mods for Xbox 360 Minecraft.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags. Both tag autocomplete and hovering your mouse over the tag both show you what the tags are for. If you use the wrong tag, potentially hundreds of people get a mail about a topic they don't want to get notified about.

Comment: @FabianRöling Please *do use* relevant tags. This question is currently not tagged Minecraft at all, and I have no idea which of the thirty versions is on Xbox 360.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I also don't know, it might be [tag:minecraft-console], it might be [tag:minecraft-pocket-edition], it might be [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition], … I wish someone with a bit of authority would look at [this](gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12523) and confirm whether the definition for these tags should be changed and the retagging should start. Then I could even do the majority of it, but there just has to be a decision, I won't just change around thousands of tags on my own. I've tagged this question as [tag:minecraft-console] for now, but they might also be on MCBedrock.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is no possibility to import mods into Minecraft for the Xbox 360.
On top of that, it is also against Microsoft ToS to mod or use mods for games that don't officially support them.
I did some research and could not find any legitimate way to mod the game.